# How to filter a model collection based on the selected option in dropdown list in collective form?

Tags: laravel, forms, filter, bootstrap-4, laravelcollective

I am doing a mall directory web application.
I would like to display a group of tenant list based on the drop down list option. (group by zone/floor/category)

[image]

Initially, I tried to pass the selected option of zone drop down list in form to DirectoryController through routes, but I unable to do it.

```
<!-- Part of the View -->
<div class = "panel-body bg-light">
        {{ Form::open(array('route' => array('directory.group', '$tenants', 'zone_id'))) }}
        <div class = "container-fluid bg-default">
            <table class="table table-borderless">
                <thead>
                    <th scope="col"><strong>ZONE<strong></th>
                    <th scope="col"><strong>FLOOR<strong></th>
                    <th scope="col"><strong>CATEGORY<strong></th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <!-- Zone -->
                            <div>
                                {!! Form::select('zone_id',
                                    Zone::pluck('code', 'id'), null, [
                                        'class' => 'form-control',
                                        'placeholder' => '- Select Zone -',
                                        'onchange' => 'this.form.submit()'
                                    ] )
                                !!}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <!-- Floor -->
                            <div>
                                {!! Form::select('floor_id',
                                    Floor::pluck('code', 'id'), null, [
                                        'class' => 'form-control',
                                        'placeholder' => '- Select Zone -',
                                ]) !!}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <!-- Category -->
                            <div>
                                {!! Form::select('category_id',
                                    Category::pluck('name', 'id'), null, [
                                        'class' => 'form-control',
                                        'placeholder' => '- Select Zone -',
                                ]) !!}
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

**DirectoryController**

```php
/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 * @param array $tenants
 * @param int $zone_id
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function group($tenants, $zone_id)
{
    $tenants = $tenants->where('zone_id', $zone_id);

    return view('directory.index', [
        'tenants' => $tenants,
    ]);

}
```

My concept is pass in a tenants list to DiretoryController@group and the function will filter based of the selected option of drop down list and pass back the new tenants list back to the view and display it.

I would much appreciate it if there was any suggestion or solution.

Comment: If one of the below posts answered your question **please may you mark it as accepted** :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind onchange to select and call ajax on every change event.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#zone_id').on('change',function () {
            var id = this.value;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'url',
                data: {
                    id:id
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (json) {
                    $('#zone_id').html(' ');
                    $.each(json, function(i, value) {
                        $('#zone_id').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', i));
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! It meant a lot to me.

Answer (score 0):

Values from a form will not be passed as params to the controller method, you will need to use the [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-input) class form that. You can either use the [request()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-request) helper function:

```
request()->input('zone_id');
```

or

[Dependency injection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers)

```php
public function group(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request, $tenants)
{
    $tenants = $tenants->where('zone_id', $request->input('zone_id'));

    return view('directory.index', [
        'tenants' => $tenants,
    ]);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Hope you have a nice day